# How to obfuscate Flutter apps?

Tags: flutter, dart, deployment, obfuscation

[Flutter's wiki](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter%27s-modes#artifact-differences) mentions obfuscation is an opt-in in release mode.
And yet, the **flutter build** command has no relevant option - see:
`flutter help -v build apk`

Am I missing something here?
Did they make obfuscation the default?
Is obfuscation even relevant for flutter?

Any pointers on this would be very appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think you need obfuscatiin anyway? Dart is compiled to binary code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Does this assure me no variable/method/type names are exposed? And that my code is hard enough to reverse-compile? I come from a C# background, excuse my ignorance...

Comment: I asked mraleph about why they added the obfuscation funtionality and he mentioned that some things might be recoverable - don't remember details. I'll try to find the disvussion.

Comment: I haven't found the discussion yet but https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30524 might provide some hints.

Comment: This was it https://gitter.im/dart-lang/TALK-general?at=5ab28157bb1018b37a0d549e

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer OK, in gitter mraleph explains there are still function names by default, and that there's support for aot obfuscation. Where's the flag to enable obfuscation? There's no documentation in `flutter help -v build aot`...

Comment: The GitHub issue 30524 mentions some flags.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer 30524 talks about Dart. I see no mention of the flutter build command.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer sir do you have any link to your resource that saying the dart is directly compiled to binary code?

Comment: https://flutter.io/docs/resources/faq#how-does-flutter-run-my-code-on-android

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Obfuscation is needed - a flutter app knows its function names, which can be shown using Dart's StackTrace class. There's **under-tested** support for obfuscation. To enable it:

---

**For Android**:
Add to the file `[ProjectRoot]/android/gradle.properties` :

```
extra-gen-snapshot-options=--obfuscate
```

---

**For iOS:**
First, edit `[FlutterRoot]/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh`:
Locate the `build aot` call, and add a flag to it,

```
${extra_gen_snapshot_options_or_none}
```

defined as:

```
local extra_gen_snapshot_options_or_none=""
if [[ -n "$EXTRA_GEN_SNAPSHOT_OPTIONS" ]]; then
  extra_gen_snapshot_options_or_none="--extra-gen-snapshot-options=$EXTRA_GEN_SNAPSHOT_OPTIONS"
fi
```

To apply your changes, in [FlutterRoot], run

```
git commit -am "Enable obfuscation on iOS"  
flutter
```

(Running "flutter" after the commit rebuilds flutter tools.)

Next, in your project, add following to `[ProjectRoot]/ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig` file:

```
EXTRA_GEN_SNAPSHOT_OPTIONS=--obfuscate
```

---

*PS: Haven't tried the --save-obfuscation-map flag mentioned at  https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30524

Again, obfuscation **isn't** very well **tested**, as mentioned by @mraleph.*

Comment: Does this current obfuscation technique make it hard for reverse engineering the code or is there any additional steps which we can follow to make it difficult for reverse engineering?

Comment: I can't find xcode_backend.sh where is that file located, /packages doesn't exists on this location too. The only /packages folder is located on /ios/Flutter/App.framework/flutter_assets/packages but it doesn't contain flutter_tools.

Comment: @i6x86 I believe you are looking under your own project by mistake - xcode_backend.sh resides in your Flutter install location. (Either that or Flutter changed since I answered. Either way, please let me know)

Comment: thanks man, you're right I was looking the project folder, my mistake.

Comment: Where to define this? local extra_gen_snapshot_options_or_none=""
if [[ -n "$EXTRA_GEN_SNAPSHOT_OPTIONS" ]]; then
  extra_gen_snapshot_options_or_none="--extra-gen-snapshot-options=$EXTRA_GEN_SNAPSHOT_OPTIONS"
fi

Comment: @JustineMackay before the call to build aot .

Comment: Hi, is this the only way to obfuscate an .ipa?

Answer (score 29):

#### AppBundle (recommended):

- ##### Without splitting:

  ```
  flutter build appbundle --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/<directory>
  ```
- ##### Splitting:

  ```
  flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/<directory>
  ```

---

#### APK:

- ###### Without splitting:

  ```
  flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/<directory>
  ```
- ##### Splitting:

  ```
  flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/<directory>
  ```

**PS: About Splitting:**
By default, fat apk contains arm v7, arm v8 and x64 which increases apk size, which you don't want to. So, when you split it, you have separate binaries which you can upload on the store and thus reducing the size of the apk that a user would need to download.

Comment: What do you mean by "splitting"?

Comment: Thank you, I read it right after asking in the official documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate, it will still be helpful for people who limit themselves to this page! You may want to edit your answer to add this precision.

Comment: Note that appbundle is recommended as size matters. It can tremendously reduce the size of your app.

Answer (score 15):

All the above answers are correct, but no answer tells you that we need to add a relative path or directory path while generating build.

**Example using Relative Path:**

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=./ProjectFolderName/debug
```

**Example using Folder Path:**

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/Users/apple/Desktop/items/debug
```

The above command will generate a build inside the given project directory, it will create a new folder called `ProjectFolderName` or 'debug' on the respective command, and there you can find the release build.

Comment: Thanks, using the relative path helped. I thought it would do that by default but no.

Answer (score 9):

**For Android** the process is pretty clear from the doc at https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate. For Example:

```
export version=1.0.0
flutter build apk --release --shrink --obfuscate --split-debug-info=misc/mapping/${version}
```

Several files will be created such as `misc/mapping/1.0.0/app.android-arm64.symbols` (which you'll likely want to keep in VCS)

**For iOS** it's a bit less obvious since you often use the Xcode menu: `Product > Archive`

1. make an obfuscated build for iOS

```
flutter build ios --release --obfuscate --split-debug-info=misc/mapping/${version}
```

it creates file `misc/mapping/1.0.0/app.ios-arm64.symbols`

2. This will also modify `ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig` to include

```
DART_OBFUSCATION=true
SPLIT_DEBUG_INFO=misc/mapping/1.0.0
```

3. Use Xcode menu: `Product > Archive` which will uses `Release.xcconfig` which includes updated `Generated.xcconfig`

```
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
```

So your uploaded Archive will now be obfuscated (you don't need to make changes to `Release.xcconfig`)

See also - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64626#issuecomment-736081173

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How could I add the *.symbols to google play?

Comment: what about web app?

Answer (score 6):

[image]
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscateRefer this link for more info

Note: Flutter’s code obfuscation, Supported as of Flutter 1.16.2.

Answer (score 6):

For iOS edit `ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig`

This file should contain something like

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
```

If you check `Generated.xcconfig` there is a line `DART_OBFUSCATION=false`

So add opposite to the end of the `Release.xcconfig` file to override:

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"

DART_OBFUSCATION=true
SPLIT_DEBUG_INFO=obj_maps
```

You can optionally add `TREE_SHAKE_ICONS=true` here to tree-shake icons as well

Comment: Great! I didn't know about the iOS part, but even after adding `DART_OBFUSCATION=true` in `Release.xcconfig` file and doing a build, the `Generated.xcconfig` file still shows `DART_OBFUSCATION=false`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad `Generated.xcconfig` doesn't matter, because we reassigning it's value in `Release.xcconfig` after including generated one. However I didn't found a way to verify that it's actually working)

Answer (score 3):

At the moment obfuscation is not directly exposed via the flutter CLI.

You can try to explicitly pass arguements to the `gen_snapshot` like this:

```
flutter build --extra-gen-snapshot-options=--obfuscate,--save-obfuscation-map=build/symbols.json --release
```

Note: that obfuscation support is not very well tested and might not work at the moment.

Comment: Does not work:
Could not find an option named "extra-gen-snapshot-options".

Comment: What about `flutter build aot --extra-gen-snapshot-options=...`?

Comment: `flutter build aot` seems to respond to the flag, but where's the apk/ipa?

Comment: `flutter build aot` unfortunately does not build APK, I looked at the code and currently it does not seem like you have a way to build ipk and also pass these flags. You would have to edit flutter_tools sources.

Comment: @mraleph I managed setting the extra-gen-snapshot-options flag via Gradle's gradle.properties, and got a working & obfuscated apk.
What's the equivalent for this in iOS?

Comment: I don't know about those parts of Flutter tooling.

Answer (score 0):

To obfuscate Dart code in a Flutter:

Update your `pubspec.yaml` file to include the `flutter_dotenv` and `flutter_obfuscate` packages:

```
 dependencies:
  flutter_dotenv: ^3.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_obfuscate: ^1.0.0
```

Create an .env file in the root of your Flutter project and define the following environment variable:

```
DART_OBFUSCATION=true
```

In your `main.dart` file, import the `flutter_dotenv` package and modify the main function as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await dotenv.load();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Build the Flutter project using the --release flag to generate a release build:
*>`flutter build apk --release`*

After the build process completes, run the following command to obfuscate the Dart code: *>`flutter pub run flutter_obfuscate`*

The obfuscated code will be placed in the `lib_obfuscated` directory.

Comment: the package flutter_obfuscate doesn't appear to exist?