# Flutter: where is xcode_backend.sh?

Tags: flutter

In the doc https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Obfuscating-Dart-Code, it says:

`Add the following flag to the build aot call in the <ProjectRoot>/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh file`.

But I don't have the directory `<ProjectRoot>/packages/` at all. Do I have to create it somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess there's a mistake on the official documentation.

**UPDATE**: the wiki page has now been [corrected](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25421)

It's not

```
<ProjectRoot>/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh
```

but should be (and it's)

```
<FlutterRoot>/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh
```

If you don't remember where you have installed flutter sdk try this command:

```
which flutter
```

it will show

```
<FlutterRoot>/bin/flutter
```

Then you will see your file in `<FlutterRoot>`

```
cd <FlutterRoot>
find . -name "xcode_backend.sh"
./packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh
```

At least the official docs points out that this feature is

> [image]

And point to this useful [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542764/how-to-obfuscate-flutter-apps).

Comment: yeah, you are right. The official doc is wrong. Thank you very much for the detail answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually I found that issue about 6 hours ago and subscribed it. ^_^ Cheers.

Comment: Ahah! I've also spoken Italian! (too much multitasking...) ^^. Glad to know you have found my issue! Gunter has already put it on a milestone. C'ya! \(ᵔᵕᵔ)/

Answer (score 23):

I had same issue and I was able to fix this by adding Flutter SDK path in User-Defined Settings. Open Project Target and add User-Defined Setting with key name FLUTTER_ROOT with the value of your flutter SDK location. Image below for further reference.

[image]

Comment: i have download flutter project but not setup flutter in my system, so it is compulsory flutter installed in system ?

Comment: yes you have to install flutter and check whether flutter installed correctly by giving command flutter doctor

Comment: Finally fixed this for me. Thanks

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.  worked for me because this `FLUTTER_ROOT` wasn’t defined in debug option.

Comment: save my day , it's work with me thank you