# How to reduce the possibility/completely prevent the possibility of reverse engineering a flutter app?

Tags: android, encryption, flutter, dart, android-security

I recently read a couple of blogs and realized that apart from obsufication there is no proper way by which we can prevent the reverse engineering of a Flutter app.

Is there any manual or proper way to ensure that atleast the **encryption logic** of storing certain **encrypted** values in Sharedpreferences remains untraceable or impossible to decode/know?

It would be great if there could be some way to make the entire logic of the app untraceable.

Comment: No that's not possible. You can only make it more difficult but not impossible. Instead, I highly suggest you don't store sensitive information in your app/app data

Comment: So how where should I store those sort of information?

Comment: I thought that Sharedpreferences would be a safe place to store the information...Provided the phone isn't rooted

Comment: here are some ways to obfuscate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542764/how-to-obfuscate-flutter-apps

Comment: Why do you not use common encryption algorithms and generate keys in ways it is currently being done?

Comment: @Mystic monk What else can be done apart from obsufication?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot What if the client is able to access or decode or know the logic which is being used in for encryption? Can a phone be rooted while it's on? Is there any way to access sharedpreferences without root?

Comment: Any sensitive operations should only be done at the server end. App is meant to contain only UI code. In your case you can still run your complex sensitive operations in the backend and continuously stream the data to the frontend. Doing massive amount of activity on the app might not be good for the battery life as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend having the logic behind the app residing on a back-end server then push the results into the client app.

I have my application doing the calculations on cloud functions with a database trigger then push the result into the database where i have the client listening for the changes. Even my payments processing is done from the server.

Comment: Is there any way the client can listen to or track the network calls being made through his phone?

Comment: what do you mean by network calls?

Comment: The HTTP requests that are made from that client's device, the results perhaps...

Comment: A client can do anything you want it to do @Father-in-lawofStackoverflow... your biggest problem will be how it operates with the data. For me what i advocate for is, just store insensitive data offline. Sensitive data should never reside on the device.

Comment: For me using FIrebase is a little bit safer because am putting my trust in a well researched service. I don't think i can create a better client-server service like the way google have. So i just don't reinvent the wheel...

Comment: I just want to store the encrypted data as long as the app is active (in background too). Can the client know what what is the original value once it's decrypted for use?

Comment: Even I'm using firebase but I need a specific sensitive value for an operation to constantly be performed until the client wishes to stop the operation.