# app:compileFlutterBuildRelease error while building app flutter

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter

Running "flutter pub get" in source...                              5.9s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Codepoint 58848 not found in font, aborting.

Target aot_android_asset_bundle failed: FontSubset error: Font subsetting failed with exit code -1.

build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:

Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 838

- What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 52s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                            175.2s (!)
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1

app:build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
  }
 }

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with 
flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

 def flutterVersionCode = 
 localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
 if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
 flutterVersionCode = '1'
 } 

 def flutterVersionName =      localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
 if (flutterVersionName == null) {
     flutterVersionName = '1.0'
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
 apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

 def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
 def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
 if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
 keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
 }

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 28

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.indianstore.onlineshopping"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    resConfigs "en"
}

signingConfigs {
    release {

        if (System.getenv()["CI"]) { // CI=true is exported by Codemagic
            storeFile file(System.getenv()["FCI_BUILD_DIR"] +      "/indianstorekey.jks")
            storePassword System.getenv()["FCI_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"]
            keyAlias System.getenv()["FCI_KEY_ALIAS"]
            keyPassword System.getenv()["FCI_KEY_PASSWORD"]
        } else {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
     }

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release`      works.
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
     }
     compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     }
 }

 flutter {
     source '../..'
 }

 dependencies {
     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
     implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


 }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }
```

Comment: have you get any solution?

Comment: No bro not yet, Did you have the same problem

Comment: yes I had.
I was using MaterialIcons font in my pubspec.yaml, I just remove that.

Comment: Can you see my pubspec.yaml and let me know which part i should remove

Comment: Have you got any solution for this problem?

Comment: @KalpeshMayani No bro

Comment: @shivakumarnani Android Studio -> Tools -> Flutter -> Open Android module in Android Studio -> Open in New Window -> Clean project and generate signed apk
Worked like charm!

Comment: this solve my problem [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76375385/13377344)

Answer (score 8):

Got the same issue.
With `flutter build appbundle --verbose` I got the root cause. It was based in custom icons, which I've built long time ago with http://fluttericon.com/.

So there are 3 possible solutions:

1. add flag "--no-tree-shake-icons"
2. remove custom icons
3. re-generate custom icons again

And everything will work!

Answer (score 3):

this will work!!!

flutter clean,
flutter pub get,
flutter build appbundle --release  --no-tree-shake-icons

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same exception when using [font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter) package.

```
[   +2 ms] [   +4 ms] Codepoint 62694 not found in font, aborting.
[   +3 ms] [  +23 ms] Codepoint 62488 not found in font, aborting.
[   +1 ms] [  +47 ms] Target aot_android_asset_bundle failed: IconTreeShakerException: Font subsetting failed with exit code 255.
[        ]            To disable icon tree shaking, pass --no-tree-shake-icons to the requested flutter build command
[  +43 ms]            #0      IconTreeShaker.subsetFont (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/icon_tree_shaker.dart:217:7)
```

finally, I took build with `flutter build apk --no-tree-shake-icons`

Answer (score 2):

go to privacy & security settings in u mac and allow access. Run build again and allow access in popup dialog

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think this line shows the error:

```
Codepoint 58848 not found in font, aborting.
```

Check your `pubspec.yaml` and see if this error comes from any library. Also does you code work on debug mode? Did you add any fonts in your pubspec file?

Comment: In pubspec.yaml there are only 164 lines bro

Answer (score 1):

Hey I've had the same issue, and the problem was that I've used icon which is no longer exists in flutter material icons.

concrete it was `Icons.key` so check all your used `Icons` if they are exists ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem happened because of given a wrong path to "--split-debug-info"

I have written

```
flutter build appbundle --release --no-tree-shake-icons --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/SunaMobile/debug
```

But the correct one is (dot was missing, so I added):

```
flutter build appbundle --release --no-tree-shake-icons --obfuscate --split-debug-info=./SunaMobile/debug
```

If you want you can give absolute path to "--split-debug-info". Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65169810/19088150

Answer (score 0):

Kindly ensure that you are on the Flutter Stable Channel by running :

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade --force
```

Then when you rebuild, the error will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem.
Open FontAwesomeIcons.dart class, search for E5E0 (hex of 58848) and remove lines, save file, then build again.

Answer (score 0):

If using any custom icon using unicode . just remove and it will work fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76142866/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)