# Flutter APK not build in Mac m2 “font-subset” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software

Tags: android, flutter, apk

“font-subset” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

Building without sound null safety ⚠️
Dart 3 will only support sound null safety, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

Target aot_android_asset_bundle failed: IconTreeShakerException: Font subsetting failed with exit code -9.

To disable icon tree shaking, pass --no-tree-shake-icons to the requested flutter build command

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Answer (score 26):

The `IconTreeShakerException: Font subsetting failed with exit code -9` error typically indicates that the Flutter `tree_shake_icons` setting is enabled, but it encountered an issue while trying to remove unused icons from your app's package to reduce the size of the app.

While `flutter build ipa --no-tree-shake-icons` works, it might impact the size of your app.

What you can do is:

- Go to system preferences > Privacy and Security
- Scroll down a bit.

You should see this:
[image]

Press `allow anyway`, you might have to build again.

Answer (score 9):

When you get the pop-up, select Show in Finder:

[image]

Then right-click the file and select open ([source](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/apple-cant-check-app-for-malicious-software-mchleab3a043/mac)):

[image]

Confirm that you want to open the file and it will be added as an exception to your mac.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the commands below:

IOS:

```
flutter build ipa --no-tree-shake-icons
```

Android:

```
flutter build appbundle --no-tree-shake-icons
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to tell your Mac that you are happy to use this code that hasn't been notarised with Apple. To do this:

1. Open up Mac's **System Settings**
2. Navigate to **Privacy and Security**
3. Scroll down until you see a section titled '**Security**'
4. If you've just attempted to build an app bundle, you'll see a font-subset section with a button to '**allow anyway**'. Tap this and then attempt to rebuild your app bundle - it should work.